# javascript calculation not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple calculator in js for my father's website.

I have a few texboxes with user inputs that should calc fine, but it refuses to work.
I simply cannot figure out what is wrong with it!
http://jsfiddle.net/xjsc16x/WgKmn/

```
function foundationcalc() {
var height = parseFloat(document.getElementById("height").value, 0);
var thickness = parseFloat(document.getElementById("thickness").value, 0);
thickness = thickness / 12;
var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById("length").value, 0);
var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("width").value, 0);
var calc1 = height * thickness * length
calc1 = calc1 / 27;
var calc2 = height * thickness * width
calc2 = calc2 / 27;
var total = (2 * calc1) + (2 * calc2);
total = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("output").value = total;
}
```

I originally had `(height * thickness * length) / 27`, but I changed it in the hopes that that might be the error. no dice. Does anyone know of a javascript debugger where you can see the values of variables live? Would be a huge help to me!

Comment: The built-in WebKit debugger can do that. Also, why are you passing `0` to `parseFloat`? `parseFloat` doesn’t take a second argument.

Comment: A simple, though admittedly not great way, to check the values is to just add extra alert(variablename) statements.

Comment: What's your problem?  You need a debugger?  Try Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: parseFloat(argument); parseFloat only take a single string argument, what's the second argument, zero for?  And use Firefox with Firebug console, very nice step debugging available.

Comment: Given the default values of 6, 18, 20, and 15, what should the answer be? What is the actual formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that jsFiddle wraps your code in an `onload` handler by default. Changing it to reside directly in `<head>` [fixes the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/WgKmn/3/).

Comment: Or giving an id to the button and putting `document.getElementById('butt').onclick = foundationcalc;` in the script.

Comment: @dystroy One more nice thing about not using `onclick=`

Comment: Also, if you just skip jsFiddle altogether, everything works.

Comment: @dystroy: [I’d use `onsubmit` for Enter, personally.](http://jsfiddle.net/WgKmn/8/)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add

```
window.onload = foundationcalc();
```

This will run the script at window loading.

Comment: No, this will run the function immediately and not assign an event handler at all. Besides, the correct `window.load = foundationcalc;` was already in the fiddle.

Comment: No. When you run the code in f fiddle it does not work because you need to add (). Check for yourself before you disregard a simple answer. Sometimes people over complicate things. The copy and past my code below into js fiddle it will work and calculate as desired.

Comment: //replace the ending statement window.onload = foundationcalc; with below 

window.onload = foundationcalc();

Comment: No, that’s not how functions work. Really. `foundationcalc()` calls the function. `foundationcalc` makes it an event handler. This happens to work because the jsFiddle isn’t set up quite right.

Comment: But don’t take my word for it! Try it yourself. Load your updated jsFiddle, then change one of the values and press the button.